# What does mnemonic means in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext

What does **mnemonic** attribute  mean in sublime text?

Because i found it in some **Main.sublime-menu** files and it is written like that :

```
"mnemonic":  "O" // or any other letter instead of O
```

It is used many times in sublime text packages, but now i said to myself it is time to  know what does it mean and why it is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mnemonic), ***mnemonic*** means

> a device such as a pattern of letters, ideas, or associations that assists in remembering something.

and from [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28287/mnemonic):

> Mnemonics are used in computing to provide users with a means to quickly access a function, service or process, bypassing the actual more lengthy method used to perform or achieve it.

In Sublime (and most software), the mnemonic is the underlined letter in a menu item that allows you to choose that item using the keyboard. For example, in the following `.sublime-menu` entry:

```js
[
    {
        "caption": "File",
        "mnemonic": "F",
        "id": "file",
        "children":
        [
            { "command": "new_file", "caption": "New File", "mnemonic": "N" },
```

the **`F`** in **`File`** will be underlined, and within that menu, the **`N`** in **`New File`** will be as well. So, on Windows or Linux, for example, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to open the **`File`** menu, then hit <kbd>N</kbd> to choose **`New File`**.